# iOS: sizeWithFont for single character is different than in a string?

Tags: ios, position, width, uilabel, character

I am trying to determine the precise position of a character in a UILabel, say:

(UILabel *)label.text = @"Hello!";

I'd like to determine the position of the 'o'. I thought that I could just sum the widths of all the preceding characters (or the whole preceding string) using sizeWithFont. The width value I get though is bigger by about 10% than what it should be. Summing the widths of individual letters (i.e. [@"H" sizeWithFont...] + [@"e" sizeWithFont...] + l... + l...) accumulates more error than [@"Hell" sizeWithFont...].

Is there a way of accurately determining the position of a single glyph in a string?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but not in a UILabel and not using sizeWithFont:.

I recently worked with Apple Developer Support, and apparently sizeWithFont: is actually an approximation. It becomes less accurate when your text (1) wraps across multiple lines and (2) contains non-latin characters (i.e. Chinese, Arabic), both of which cause line spacing changes not captured by sizeWithFont:. So, don't rely on this method if you want 100% accuracy.

Here are two things you can do:

(1) Instead of UILabel, use a non-editable UITextView. This will support the UITextInput protocol method [firstRectForRange:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInput/firstRectForRange:), which you can use to get the rect of the character you need. You could use a method like this one:

```
- (CGRect)rectOfCharacterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)characterIndex inTextView:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // set the beginning position to the index of the character
    UITextPosition *beginningPosition = [textView positionFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument offset:characterIndex];
    // set the end position to the index of the character plus 1
    UITextPosition *endPosition = [textView positionFromPosition:beginningPosition offset:1];
    // get the text range between these two positions
    UITextRange *characterTextRange = [textView textRangeFromPosition:beginningPosition toPosition:endPosition]];
    // get the rect of the character
    CGRect rectOfCharacter = [textView firstRectForRange:characterTextRange];
    // return the rect, converted from the text input view (unless you want it to be relative the text input view)
    return [textView convertRect:rectOfCharacter fromView:textView.textInputView];
}
```

To use it, (assuming you have a UITextView called myTextView already on the screen), you would do this:

```
myTextView.text = @"Hello!";
CGRect rectOfOCharacter = [self rectOfCharacterAtIndex:4 inTextView:myTextView];
// do whatever you need with rectOfOCharacter
```

Only use this method for determining the rect for *ONE* character. The reason for this is that in the event of a line break, firstRectForRange: only returns the rect on the first line, before the break.

Also, consider adding the method above as a UITextView category if you're gong to be using it a lot. Don't forget to add error handling!

You can learn more about how firstRectForRange: works "under the hood" by reading the [Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4-SW43).

(2) Create your own UILabel by subclassing UIView and using Core Text to render the strings.   Since you're doing the rendering, you'll be able to get the positions of characters. This approach is a lot of work, and only worthwhile if you really need it (I, of course, don't know the other needs of your app). If you aren't sure how this would work, I suggest using the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well fonts are smart now a day and take in respect the position of a character to its pervious character.

Here is an example on how the starting position of the letter `o`:

```
NSRange posRange = [hello rangeOfString:@"o"];
NSString *substring = [hello substringToIndex:posRange.location];
CGSize size = [substring sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
```

No you can do the same for the string including the letter `o` and substract the size found in the string without the letter `o`.
THis should give the an nice start position of the letter and the size.

Answer (score 0):

in ios6 you can do using attributed string

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *titleText2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strHello];
    NSRange posRange = [hello rangeOfString:@"o"];


    [titleText2 addAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] forKey:NSFontAttributeName] range:NameRange];
```

and set your textView with this attributed string